Where Kile editor keyboard shortcuts are stored?
I use Kile editor Version 2.9.93, Ubuntu 23.10 and want to backup keyboard shortcuts configuration for Kile. Where it is stored? I found in ~/.config two files:
kile-livepreview-okularpartrc and kilerc but didn't find user specified keyboard shortcuts there...
P.S. in similar questions some refer to ~/.kde or ~/.kde4 but they are missing in my case.
